# URL doesn't exist after creating

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here's my **views.py**:

```
class LanguageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Language.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = LanguageSerializer


class FrameworkViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Framework.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FrameworkSerializer


class SelectedLanguageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Language.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FrameworkSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        language_id = request.query_params.get('language_id')
        language = Language.objects.filter(id=language_id)
        self.queryset = language.framework_set.all()
        return self.queryset
```

And my **urls.py**:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'languages', views.LanguageViewSet)
router.register(r'frameworks', views.FrameworkViewSet)
router.register(r'language/<int:language_id>', views.SelectedLanguageViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

However, only `languages` and `frameworks` work. `language` doesn't exists. Is this because of the `get_queryset`? I even tried removing the `<int:language_id>` in the url params but it still won't show up.

EDIT:
**Forgive my naiveness, I'm quite new to django and DRF**

### Update

What I meant to do was like this (without DRF):
In the **views.py**:

```
def frameworks_from_language(request, language_id):
    language = Language.objects.get(pk=language_id)

    if language == None:
        # Do some stuffs

    frameworks = language.framework_set.all()
    template = 'app/language.html'
    context = {
        'frameworks': frameworks
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

And in **urls.py**:

```
path('language/<int:language_id>', views.frameworks_from_language, name='getframeworks')
```

So the whole flow would be:

1. User clicks a language
2. Fire a get request based on the id of the selected language
3. Return an object of frameworks that is related to the language

This is working on a normal template-based Django. However I have no idea how to execute something like this on DRF, with all the viewsets etc.

Comment: What is the error code and message you get?

Comment: @TajinderSingh `Page not found (404) Request: GET`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's because of your `get_queryset` (and your URL definitions).

At first, drop `<int:language_id>` from URL prefix, as DRF router generates the list and detail URL endpoints for you automatically. Moreover, as you're using Regex path `language/<int:language_id>` is taken literally (`<int:language_id>` has a meaning while using `path`, not `re_path`).

In your `SelectedLanguageViewSet.get_queryset`, you're trying to return all `Framework` instances related with a certain `Language` (you thought you would take that from `language_id` query param). The viewset is for `Language` model, and at most you should do some filtering on the default `queryset` inside `get_queryset`; absolutely don't return a whole different queryset from another model. What will happen (after fixing your URL) when you pass `/language/1/`? (Will 1 be a `Language` ID or a `Framework` ID ? **Hint:** as per you current design it would refer a `Framework` instance ID).

FWIW, the URL captures come as `kwargs` attribute in a viewset instance (i.e. `self.kwargs`), not via the query string.

---

**Answer to edits:**

To implement that in DRF, you can define a serializer for language with only the `frameworks` field:

```
from viewsets import ReadOnlyModelViewSet

class SelectedLanguageViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Language.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LangaugeRelationSerializer
```

only `list` and `retrieve` actions should be supported, hence inherited from `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`.

Now, the serializer (with only one field -- `frameworks`):

```
class LangaugeRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    frameworks = FrameworkSerializer(source='framework_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ('frameworks',)
```

By default `ModelSerializer` sets the related fields as `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, so the related objects are represented as their primary keys. If you want that instead of using the `FrameworkSerializer`:

```
class LangaugeRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    frameworks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='framework_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ('frameworks',)
```

As `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` is the default, you can also define the `source` in `Meta.extra_kwargs` (to save you from writing the field definition yourself):

```
class LangaugeRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ('frameworks',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'frameworks': {
                'source': 'framework_set',
                'many': True,
            },
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I have updated the question for further clarification :)

Comment: Thank you!! One last thing, how about in the `urls.py`? what should be the proper codes in there to connect?

Comment: @DranDev Use the (unique) prefix you like e.g. `router.register('selected-language', views.SelectedLanguageViewSet)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing url as `/language/id-of-language` in the place of `id-of-language` pass integer i.e. the id for language in the db.